# ¿Como puedo probar una tarea programada usando huey?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Necesito crear una prueba unitaria para una tarea programada(schedule), la tarea funciona perfectamente pero en los tests siempre me retorna None:

```
update_task_id = update_delivery_minutes_change.schedule(
    args=(instance.id,),
    delay=(60 * 30)
)
update_task_id.task.task_id -> None
```

Esto se debe a que la tarea no se programa porque se ejecuta inmediatamente, como puedo evitar esto? necesito el id de la tarea para guardarlo en cache.